# Unable to upgrade 12.04 LTS to 12.10, failed to fetch error

Tags: upgrade

```
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
```

Also if I can directly upgrade to any other latest version, please suggest how I can do so.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Canonical has deleted the software repositories of 12.10, since it was only supported until mid-2014. That would result in a 404 Not Found error. You should be able to upgrade directly from 12.04 to 14.04, though (I think?).

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo apt-get update` to get new package information.

Note, however, that you should be able to run `do-release-upgrade` to jump to the max possible version of Ubuntu that the system is able to upgrade to. Sometimes, you may need to go through key steps first, but this is the most direct way to upgrade your distro.